# Align 2 columns equally in excel

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns in excel col1 and col2. Both have same data. I want to align col2 as per col1 as col1 is master data.
For ex:

```
    col1        col2      col3
    abc          ghi       jjj
    def          abc       222
    ghi          def       666
    mmm
    lll
```

I want to organize the col2 data as col1 and also col1 will have data that is not present in col2. I want to retain all data in col1. I also want to retain the mapped data from col3 w.r.t col2

My result should look like

```
    col1        col2      col3
    abc          abc      222
    def          def      666
    ghi          ghi      jjj
    mmm
    lll
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Try `Index/Match` combination like-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(D2,$B$2:$B$6,0)),"")
```

`VLOOKUP()` will also work.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,$B$2:$B$6,1,FALSE),"")
```

[image]

Comment: What if I add col3 and want to retain col3 data with col2

Comment: For `Col3` formula will be `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MATCH(E2,$B$2:$B$6,0)),"")`.

Comment: I have around 15,000 rows but when this formula is applied it copies only first row into column E--  =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$15000, MATCH(D2,$B$2:$B$15000,0)),"")

Comment: Only first row! Match, vlookup always display result from first matching. You may need to use some filtering formula. What is your `Excel` version? Can you please explain little more with data.

Comment: 16.0.1312  --32 bit

Comment: My data -UIJK199.99